# How to get the LCID from std::locale

Tags: c++, locale, crt, lcid

In windows how to get the LCID from the std::locale

```
locale l1(".OCP");//get the default system locale
cout<<l1.c_str()<<endl;
```

In previous code i get the name of the locale but the win32 LCID this is the required one

Comment: The code shown in the questing used a non-conforming extension which I'm trying to [remove](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/3088). Are there any other usages of `std::locale::c_str()`?

Comment: I don't think so, and upgrade will not be much effort I think. thanks for the update

Answer (score 1):

The only identifying entity associated with a `std::locale()` is its `name():

```
std::cout << l1.name() << '\n';
```

The content of this attribute is rather weakly specified but in the above setup it should have a name and yield something different from `"*"` which is what is returned for unnamed locales. What the name is, isn't specified, however.

Comment: I now that and I asked about the win32 LCID

Comment: We can use the name to create _locale_t instance and then use the solution in this link, it give a correct LCID but I don't know if it is trusted solution!? http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?513199-Get-LCID-from-CRT-s-_locale_t